# activate .gif nested in WordPress on mouseenter/mouseleave with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, animated-gif, mouseenter

I am pretty new to jQuery and I am running into some issues with changing image attributes.

Problem: In WordPress, I uploaded both a .png file and a .gif to show the evolution of my design. I have given the image an ID (#tp-ia-gif) and I hope to achieve the effect that a cursor hover fires the animated gif (similar to Youtube hover or [this demo](http://docs.embed.ly/docs/tutorial-play-and-stop-gifs)). The snippet I wrote looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(#tp-ia-gif).mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).attr("src", "http://judithleng.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/IA-evolution.gif");
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "http://judithleng.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/IA-evolution.png")}); });
```

I have successfully enqueued jQuery into WordPress and I'm not sure why this script is not working. I would have pasted the HTML code over but since the image is nested pretty deep it would be a lot of code, but I can share a link if that's helpful. Thanks in advance for any helpful insights!
`

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the developer console? Also, it is not necessary to enqueue jQuery, it is included with Wordpress by default. If you want to include your own version, you need to first dequeue the one that comes bundled.

Comment: Just noticed an error, you need to pass `$` into the function to be able to use it within the document ready function: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` My guess is that you are currently getting an error along the lines of `$ is not defined`.

Comment: Hi @APAD1 :) Thanks - I just took a look at the Javascript console on Chrome and the error I was getting an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token". I tried passing $ into the function but the error persisted. Also, I thought jQuery came with Wordpress too, but I just commented out my enqueue function for jQuery and the alert test script stopped working..